# how to find min/max axis length across the centroid of a closed curve

Tags: python, geometry, medical-imaging

I'm doing a segmentation task. Now I successfully segmented the area of interest and find the contour of the area. How can I calculate the min/max axis length of the contour? The axis does not have to be orthogonal.

What I already got are:
coordinates of points on the contour.
centroid of the contour.

What I already tried:
I have found a fitting-ellipse of the contour. However, fitting-ellipse can only find the orthogonal axis which might not be the minimum or maximum length across the centroid.

Comment: Search for "calipers"; it's a package that can do just what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the contour, you might want to do this:
for alpha = 0 to 45 degrees, rotate the contour by alpha, draw a line over the centroid of your contour that is parallel to X-axis, find out the intersection points of this line and the contour, that is one "axis" at current angle alpha. continue rotating the contour and find more of such "axis", find the longest one as your max axis, shortest one as your min axis.